# Can halting function be created without referring/assembling/generation of the solver in the input?

Tags: halting-problem

The question is: can the halting problem be solved if the solver is not being assembled/emulated/generated/recreated/put your choice here/used in any form inside the analyzed function?

There is a very similar question:
[Is it possible to make a halting function if you don't call it on itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088336/is-it-possible-to-make-a-halting-function-if-you-dont-call-it-on-itself)
but the answer for it is generally that "we don't call function rather we pass function", however, if we exclude such situations either, will it become solvable?

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Comment: I'm not trying to find a solution, rather are there any other contradictions, which prevent solving the halting problem except referring in some way to itself?

Comment: The solution might be a dictionary with pairs <program_with_its_input>-<halt_or_not_halt>. Of course it will require infinite memory for infinite possible inputs. But as I understand there are no limitations on resources in the halting-problem